# Pass specific info through JSON, JQuery, PHP

Tags: php, jquery, json

My PHP:

```
if($count == 1 && $user_level < 4 && $if_active == 1)
{
$response = array("success" => true); 

//The login stuff happens here

echo json_encode($response); 
}

elseif($count == 1 && $user_level < 4 && $if_active == 0)
{
$response = array("success" => not_act);  
echo json_encode($response);  
}
else 
{
$response = array("success" => false); 
echo json_encode($response); 
}
```

The JQuery that sends and recieves the data from that PHP file

```
$('#login_form').submit(function(){ 
        var emailB = encodeURIComponent($('#email_B').val());   
        var passwordB = encodeURIComponent($('#password_B').val());   
        $('#wrapper').fadeOut(); 
        $('#login_effect').fadeIn(); 
        $.ajax({ 
            type: 'POST', url: 'checklogin.php',  dataType: "json",  data: { email: emailB, password: passwordB,  }, 
            success: function(result) {                 
                if (!result.success) { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 1500); $('#wrong_password').fadeIn(); }  
                else if (result.success == not_act) {timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 1500); $('#not_act').fadeIn();}
                else { timeout = setTimeout(function(){ $('#login_effect').fadeOut(); }, 1500); document.location.href='http://matchmingle.net/profile/'; } 
            }  
        }); 
        return false; 
    });
```

This works fine and dandy EXCEPT for the not activated part. How do I find out in the JQuery what the JSON returned besides just true and false? I tried to

```
$response = array("success" => not_act);
```

and then in the JQUery

```
else if (result.success == not_act) {do cool stuff}
```

but I can't get it to work because I'm obviously doing it wrong. BTW I'm very new to this JQuery/JSON/Javascript, what you're seeing me do is what I've learned from a dummies book over the corse of a few weeks and a bunch of help from you guys.

So yeah, what's the proper way to set the json response variable and find out what it's value is in the JQuery?
Thanks a bunch
-Mike

Comment: Why are you using unquoted strings? They work in PHP if they are a valid but undefined constant name, but in pretty much every other language they luckily don't.

Comment: TheifMaster is right, not_act without quotes causes PHP to look for a constant named not_act, and when it doesn't find one, it uses the string literal "not_act" instead. this is an unfortunate quirk in PHP that encourages bad coding habits. always use quotes or <<< when defining string literals.

Comment: yeah it was something so stupid I over looked, embarrassedface.jpg

Comment: I appreciate you guys taking the time to look at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that you need to add quote mark

in your php:

```
$response = array("success" => "not_act");
```

and in your javascript:

```
else if (result.success == "not_act") {/*do cool stuff*/}
```

because not_act seem to be a variable name, and I don't see if this variable have the same value in your php code and in your javascript one.

By surrounding with quote mark, it will now be a string.

Comment: Worked perfectly!! Thank you so much! I wasn't even thinking to put it in quotations, competely over looked it, thanks a bunch man. in 4 minutes I can accept it as an answer!!

Answer (score 3):

is not_act supposed to be a string literal? if so, it needs quotes around it. also you repeat the return json_encode($response) in many different places when it only needs to be placed once after the long if else statement.

once this stuff is fixed, you will also need to make sure that your comparison on the javascript side uses a string literal as well.

```
else if (result.success == not_act) {do cool stuff}
```

the above line checks for a variable named not_act, and most likely does not find it. instead try encased in quotes:

```
else if (result.success == 'not_act') {do cool stuff}
```

also, it is recommended to use 1 for true and 0 for false when transmitting via JSON.

Comment: Thanks a bunch for taking the time to answer this!

Answer (score 1):

u can use addon like *Firebug* of *Firefox* browser that what values are returned.

```
success: function(result) {
if(result[array index] == check aganist value)
{
 //if logic
}

}
```